# Bug in integrate in in 13.1.0?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs

**Bug introduced in 13.1, and fixed in 13.2.**

---

I'm trying the following locally (13.1.0 for Mac) and getting incorrect result

```
Quit[];
Integrate[1/(x + 1)^2 Exp[-t 1/(x + 1)^2], {x, 0, \[Infinity]}] /. 
 t -> 3.  (* 0.0575796 *)
```

This answer is wrong.
I get the correct answer `0.504344` when running same expression on Wolfram Cloud (13.2.0).

Is this a bug in 13.1, corrupted local state, or something else?

Because of this, I can't rerun the notebook from this [post](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2362355) anymore, any workarounds appreciated.

Comment: v11.3 and v13.2.1 get `0.504344`, and v13.1 get `0.0575796`.

Comment: In 13.2.1 (Windows) I get `1/2 Sqrt[\[Pi]/3] Erf[Sqrt[3]]` which evaluates to `0.504344`.

Comment: The tag [tag:numerical-integration] suggests you should be using `NIntegrate` instead of `Integrate`....Perhaps this should be tagged [tag[calculus-and-analysis]? And if so, perhaps the question should be about the general result, not the numerical value at the floating-point number `3.`?

Comment: Why 3. ??? That is float, and will switch to NIntegrate and not produce nice symbolic answer. @MichaelE2 NIntegrate outright gives a warning. 13.2.1 is all good. Fixed bug.

Comment: The symbolic result of Integrate is incorrect, 3. is there to show how far off it is

Comment: What is the correct symbolic result? I get 1/2 Sqrt[\[Pi]/3] Erf[Sqrt[3]] which is N[%, 40] ==  0.5043435602314388070383233676828131509695

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников Why do you think it switches to `NIntegrate`? `Integrate` evaluates to a symbolic solution, then `3.` is substituted.

Comment: Okay. You are right.

Comment: Yaroslav, don't you think the incorrect symbolic result is the main problem and should be the highlight of the question? Right now, the emphasis on why the `3.` is causing trouble. In fact, the question seems to point to `3.` as a key factor in the problem, which it is not, if `Integrate` is wrong.  One cannot tell from reading the question that the problem lies with `Integrate` returning an incorrect solution. It might returning unevaluated until a numeric value for `t` is substituted.

Comment: What do you get if you add the assumption `t > 0` to `Integrate`?

Comment: What does `g[x_] := 1/(x+1)^2` have to do with anything?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

g[x_] = 1/(x + 1)^2;
```

The incorrect result is

```
Integrate[1/(x + 1)^2 Exp[-t 1/(x + 1)^2], {x, 0, ∞}]

(* E^(2 - t)/(-1 + E^2) *)
```

To get the correct result, do a change of variables

```
IntegrateChangeVariables[
  Inactive[Integrate][1/(x + 1)^2 Exp[-t 1/(x + 1)^2], {x, 0, ∞}], 
  u, u == x + 1]
```

[image]

```
% // Activate

(* (Sqrt[π] Erf[Sqrt[t]])/(2 Sqrt[t]) *)
```

Compare with,

```
WolframAlpha["Integrate[1/(x+1)^2 Exp[-t 1/(x+1)^2], {x, 0, ∞}]", \
{{"Input", 1}, "Content"}]
```

[image]

Comment: It is simpler to just update to 13.2.1.

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников while this is one way to think about the situation, finding work-arounds is good practice. Also, Bob gave a nice and very simple answer, so this comment is largely immaterial

Answer (score 3):

Another way of doing the integral.

```
g[x_] = 1/(x + 1)^2;

Integrate`InverseIntegrate[
  1/(x + 1)^2 Exp[-t 1/(x + 1)^2], {x, 0, ∞}] /. t -> 3.
```

> `0.504344`

which means that the above gives the correct symbolic result

```
Integrate`InverseIntegrate[
 1/(x + 1)^2 Exp[-t 1/(x + 1)^2], {x, 0, ∞}]
```

> [image: int]